# java array boolean copy without reference

Tags: java, reference

I have the following code:

```
boolean[] array1;
boolean[] array2;

array1 = new boolean[2];
array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);

for(int i = 0;i<array2.length;i++){
     array2[i]=true; 
}
```

The result is that ***array1*** also change its elements to ***true***. I think this is happening because ***array1*** is passing its reference to ***array2*** but I am not sure. Is this conclusion correct? How can I do if I want to modify ***array2*** without modifying ***array1***?

Comment: Instead of using `copyOf()` you can manually copy each element after creating `array2`

Comment: Are you sure? This should not be happening.

Comment: Does not happen in my environment

Comment: check `System.out.println(array1==array2);` output.

Comment: indeed you are right. Another part of my code was changing the value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type boolean its a primitive type, when you use Arrays.copyOf the array values are copied to the new array. So, when you modify the second array, are you modifying the array by value. I don't see any error in the code.

Comment: This is what was happening: this code is part of an Android snippet where I was trying to implement a checkbox list. the checkbox listener is who changed the value of array1.

Answer (score 1):

`copyOf` doesn't pass reference but it just copies values from one array to othe one.

Try below code as changes in b after copy isn't reflected in c.

```
boolean b[]=new boolean[]{true,false,true};

boolean c[]=new boolean[5];

c=Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length);

b[2]=false;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

output will be `[true,false,true]` as it was at the time of copy

Answer (score 1):

When I tried this code:

```
    boolean[] array1;
    boolean[] array2;

    array1 = new boolean[2];
    array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);

    for(int i = 0;i<array2.length;i++){
         array2[i]=true; 
    }
    System.out.println("array1:"+array1[0]);
```

I got answer :

```
array1:false
```

So your statement "The result is that array1 also change its elements to true." is really not true.

So `copyOf` just did what we expected.